# Stop Loading spec_helper from spec directory when running another set of tests

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

I have two spec folders. The first one is /spec and it what you typically would see. I have another called /live_integration_tests. When I run `rspec -I live_integration_tests ./live_integration_tests` I'm actually pulling in the `spec/spec_helper.rb` file as well. Is there a way to get rspec to ignore the spec_helper file in the spec_helper folder.

I've also tried `rspec -O live_integration_tests/spec_helper.rb ./live_integration_tests`
 but that didn't do it either. Everything else in the help didn't look very promising.

Comment: Are you using `require 'spec_helper'` in all test files?

Comment: Yes, it looks like `require 'spec_helper'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a fix for this.

`rspec --default-path ./live_integration_tests` runs only the rspec spec_helper in the ./live_integration_test folder and not the default one in ./spec.